# Can't Remove Page from Google

Tags: google

High. My name is Festus.

I'm creating a web site for a customer and would prefer not to have Google index the site while it's still being developed. The customer, on the other hand, must be able to access the unfinished site.

My solution was to give the site an unusual hostname. I used `myCustomerName.domainName.com` with the thought that there's no way Google would be able to guess that hostname and therefore crawl/index it.

Nevertheless, Google found and indexed the page despite my 100% certainty that there are no external sites that link to it. I found out later that someone at the customer's site had been typing `myCustomerName.domainName.com` into the Google search engine instead of the address bar. That's how Google found out about it. (I have no idea why someone would type the custom hostname into Google's searchbox instead of the address bar, but they did).

Now unfortunately the site shows up in Google as a search engine result. Here's what I've done so far.

(1) I researched robots.txt and disallowed access to the entire site.

(2) I went to Google's Page Remove tool and asked the page to be removed. I got a successful response saying that the page was in fact removed. The status is now set to "removed."

...and yet the page still appears in Google search results. Any idea why? I guess I could always rename the host to `someOTHERrandomString.myDomain.com' but I'd like to know why Google Webmaster tools show the page as "Removed" as of April 3 but it's still highly ranked on the search engine page.

According to Google: "We won't index the page if it's blocked in robots.txt and there is an active URL removal request for the page." I've done both of those things, and again, there are no external sites linking to the custom hostname.

So what's up?

Comment: How long has it been?? Search engines are notoriously slow due to volume and scale.

Comment: As @closetnoc said, time is everything here. It's been only 4 days. I suggest you wait for more time.

Comment: It took a couple of months for a page to be removed once when I needed it removed right away. It was disappointing, but patience was the key.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly did you remove it from both google search and cache ?
Secondly I consider you have removed it from both cache and search , so I suggest you to wait for some time.
Third , if you don't want google to crawl your website and any of the links to it then deny access to whole website in your robots.txt.
As well as to sitemap.xml of your website. remove the sitemap from webmasters also.

This helped me when I had this kind of issue, It will help you too.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I forgot that it's prohibited to provide any contacts or irrelevant links .

Comment: I used the Google removal tool so it's *supposedly* going to be removed from Google Search. What did you mean about "cache" though? That's something I haven't explored.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following html code into the head tags:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow" />
```

This prevents google and most bots from crawling and indexing your site. It also stops them from following links from your webpage